# How to resample tick data to pandas resample ohlc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert fx tick data into ohlc data:

```
import pandas as pd
data_frame = pd.read_csv('gbpusd jan17.csv', names=['Symbol', 'Date_Time', 'Bid', 'Ask'],
                         index_col=1, parse_dates=True, nrows=100)

print(data_frame.head())

data_ask = data_frame['Ask'].resample('15Min').ohlc()

data_bid = data_frame['Bid'].resample('15Min').ohlc()

data_ask.head()

data_bid.head()
print(data_ask.head())
print(data_ask[1:5])
```

My outputs are:

```
                          Symbol      Bid      Ask
Date_Time
2017-01-02 00:00:01.105  GBP/USD  1.23399  1.23551
2017-01-02 00:00:01.561  GBP/USD  1.23399  1.23551
2017-01-02 00:00:05.122  GBP/USD  1.23399  1.23551
2017-01-02 00:00:05.525  GBP/USD  1.23365  1.23577
2017-01-02 00:00:06.139  GBP/USD  1.23365  1.23577

                open     high      low    close
Date_Time
2017-01-02  1.23551  1.23633  1.23551  1.23576
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [open, high, low, close]
Index: []
```

Can anyone please tell me why I can see head of an empty dataframe? What went wrong here and how can I turn all tick data to ohlc data?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `data_ask` is a single row dataset (based on the previous `head()` statement). But when you use `[1:5]` to call the data, you're asking for the set of data starting at the second row,  thus the empty df. See what happens if you use `print(df_ask[0:5])` instead.

Comment: Thanks, it showed the 1 row df, same as the head(), with your code, any idea why it's one row instead of 100?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure as I'm not very familiar with `.resample()` and not at all familiar with `.ohlc()`, but if you're looking to break down your dataframe to 15-minute intervals when some of them are currently less than 1 second, it might just be putting all of those short intervals into a single 15-minute interval.

Comment: Hi, I got the answer; i loaded only 100 ticks which is only 5 seconds, after taking the whole file, it's showing more rows. Thanks for spending your valuable time form me.

Comment: Great, glad I could help. If this solves your problem, I'd appreciate you checked this as the answer.